# NestJs Async controller method vs calling await / async inside a method

Tags: node.js, async-await, nestjs

I'm bit new to NodeJs & NestJs. I always wondered what's the difference between using async as the method return type inside a controller vs executing async operation inside a regular method ? How does NodeJs handles the request in both these cases if there is huge traffic on this API (eg. 40K req/min). Will it be blocking in the 2nd example and non blocking in the 1st or would it work in a similar way?

For Eg:

```
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private catsService: CatsService) {}

  @Post()
  async sample() {
    return "1234";
  }
}
```

vs

```
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private catsService: CatsService) {}

  @Post()
   function sample() {
    return await methodX();
  }
  
  async function methodX(){
      return "1234"
  }
```

Please ***ignore what the content in sample() & methodX() does*** its only for example.

Comment: I think your second example should remove “await” keyword from the return statement to make your question clear and the code to be syntactically correct.

Comment: note that `return await` is syntactically correct. But the usage in there is useless since there's no error handling in `sample` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, marking a method as `async` enables you to use the `await` keyword inside of it.

For example in the second sample you provided, you need to mark the method `sample` as `async` to `await` `methodX`:

```
@Post()
async function sample() {
  // Now `await` can be used inside `sample`
  return await methodX();
}
```

So to answer your questions

> what's the difference between using async as the method return type inside a controller vs executing async operation inside a regular method ?

There is none. In both cases, the method of the controller will need to marked as `async`. Performing what the route is supposed to perform in the body of the method or extracting it in another `async` method is just a matter of code organisation.

> Will it be blocking in the 2nd example and non blocking in the 1st or would it work in a similar way?

Both examples would work in a similar way.

---

Second, marking a mehthod as `async` doesn't actually make it async if there is no real async operation performed in its body like a request to another service or a `setTimeout`. It means that the following samples

```
// Sample 1
@Post()
async sample() {
  return "1234";
}

// Sample 2
@Post()
function async sample() {
  return await methodX();
}
  
async function methodX(){
  return "1234"
}
```

Are both equivalent to the synchronous method

```
@Post()
syncSample() {
  return "1234";
}
```

---

Finally, as stated by @Micael Levi, `return await` is syntactically correct but should be avoided. Considering this sample:

```
@Post()
function async sample() {
  return await methodX();
}
  
async function methodX(){
  throw new Error('something failed')
}
```

Because the method `sample` `return await` `methodX`, `sample` won't appear in the stack trace which makes debugging more difficult.

We would prefer this sample:

```
@Post()
function async sample() {
  const result = await methodX();

  return result;
}
  
async function methodX(){
  throw new Error('something failed')
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference in returning a promise by not awaiting here. I have also seen that as a practice, but don't fully understand what that entails. Essentially, just `async methodX() { return methodY() }`. Inside the function, you are of course doing async await stuff, but you don't actually await the function return. What does the client receive as a response?

Comment: It works as well since the client receives a `Promise`. This is indeed a common pattern to return the `Promise` itself instead of awaiting it

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance under load it depends entirely on what is being awaited. Async - await patterns give a performance benefit if the awaited function is blocked (e.g. by disk access), and there is other useful work that can be done e.g. another non-IO blocked request. This allows the main thread to hand off processing to another worker thread, and then return back to it later when done. This can be very beneficial to responsiveness, as the request processing threads can execute many more requests that are long running. That's the theory.

It should be said in the trivial example you give async await will probably perform much worse under high load, as the method must paused, added to a queue, pulled off, executed, and then returned. These are expensive operations. Some JIT engines will optimise these steps away. I do not know if NodeJS has all these optimisations yet.

In my experience these kind of optimisations are hard to see in practice on requests shorter than 50ms. Above that, you will likely be concurrency locked on IO at this point which means there are other optimisations that will benefit first. Normally this involves moving slower performing blocking requests into a distinct separate microservice/process, to avoid slowing the high performance queries.

Therefore I am unfashionable, and say given the extra code burden of the pattern, I think it rarely benefits projects and should be a late stage optimisation on key services, and avoided unless you know what you're doing. Unfortunately everyone seems to have drunk the async await cool-aid and use it everywhere...